# Error in cron: bad minute errors in crontab file, can't install

Tags: cron

I am trying to run a crontab with the expression given below. But i am getting bad minute error.

This is for a Linux Server.

```
0/5 * * * *  /home/cdh_infa_user/data/pladmin/MyLinuxAgent/apps/Data_Integration_Server/data/scripts/Secureagent.sh
```

Do i need to install crontab? Please guide
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBn1p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4uWE.png)

Comment: Crontab is already installed on the system. If the script has to run at 5th hour of the day the entry should be like 0 5 * * * * <your file name> .

Answer (score 2):

To run cron every 5 minutes you need to add command like this:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/cdh_infa_user/data/pladmin/MyLinuxAgent/apps/Data_Integration_Server/data/scripts/Secureagent.sh
```

To run cron at 5 a clock you need record like this:

```
0 5 * * * /home/cdh_infa_user/data/pladmin/MyLinuxAgent/apps/Data_Integration_Server/data/scripts/Secureagent.sh
```